# Tooltip text not working properly

Tags: php, html, tooltip

I am using tooltip inside of an echo statement i.e.

```
echo "<div id='image' data-toggle='tooltip' title=".$row['displayname'].">";
```

but it only displays the first word.

suppose the $row['displayname'] returns "here is the code" then on hover it only displays "here".

So any help 
Thankyou..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping your title in '' quotes.

```
echo "<div id='image' data-toggle='tooltip' title='".$row['displayname']."'>";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't add the quotes, it will take single word as title.

```
echo "<div id='image' data-toggle='tooltip' title='".$row['displayname']."'>";
```

or

```
echo "<div id='image' data-toggle='tooltip' title=\"".$row['displayname']."\">";
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure this will work, but I think it would:

```
echo "<div id='image' data-toggle='tooltip' title='".$row['displayname']."'>";
```